# Dart simple String encoder/decorer

Tags: flutter, dart

some days a go i used [flutter_string_encryption](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_string_encryption) library in flutter and it work fine without any problem in debug mode, but when i try to build `apk` or running application i release mode, i get error

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Could not find com.github.tozny:java-aes-crypto:1.1.0.
Required by: project :app > com.github.sroddy.flutterstringencryption:flutter_string_encryption_release:1.0
```

with this library i can store key for encrypt and decrypt strings, and that work fine, now i have a problem with this library, is any equivalent like with that?

i want to i could store key in database or use that in variable as value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the [dependency - java-aes-crypto](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto) on Android side is missing.

You can try to add this to your project manually:

Add repository note to `android/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // Add this line
  }
}
```

And dependency one to `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.tozny:java-aes-crypto:1.1.0' // Add this line
  ...
}
```

This issue is also [reported](https://github.com/sroddy/flutter_string_encryption/issues/23) on the library GitHub repository.